# Clear selections of ListBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform which clears all selections of the comboboxes when the form is submitted but I cannot manage to clear the selections of the ListBoxes.

I only manage to clear one selection with this code ( if 3 options selected, 2 remain selected after running this).

```
Me.ComboBox6.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox7.Value = ""
ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
ListBox2.Selected(ListBox2.ListIndex) = False
ListBox3.Selected(ListBox3.ListIndex) = False
```

I tried looping the ListBox lines but I can't make it work...

```
For x = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox2.Selected(x) Then
 ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) = False   
End If     Next x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just loop through the controls, and if the ctrl has a name of "ListBox" do something.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ctrl As Control

    For Each Ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
            Ctrl.Selected(ListIndex) = False
        End If

    Next Ctrl

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I changed UserForm1 to the name of my form and "ListBox1" as it it the name of one of my listboxes and didn't work.    I have added the Dim and For to the end of my CommandButton2_Click(), Am I missing something else?

Comment: Thanks @Davesexcel    I tried this one and it worked:
Dim iCount As Integer

    For iCount = 0 To Me!ListBox1.ListCount
        Me!ListBox1.Selected(iCount) = False
    Next iCount

Answer (score 0):

a slightly different approach

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ctrl As msforms.Control

    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
        If Ctrl.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
        Ctrl.ListIndex = -1
        Else
        Ctrl.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
        Ctrl.ListIndex = -1
        Ctrl.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        End If
        End If
    Next Ctrl

End Sub
```